# Php session ( cart system )

Tags: php, session

```html
if (isset($_POST['lol']))
    {
     $_SESSION['cart']=array();
     $proid=$_REQUEST["proid"];
     array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$proid);
     
    }
     
    
    
    
   if (isset($_SESSION['cart']))
   {
    
    
    $total = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $proid )
    {
     $results = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from product where Product_ID = '$proid'");
     $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
     $price = $myrow['Product_Price'];
     $total =$total + $price;
      
      ?>
       <li class = "cartlist"><?php echo  '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' .        base64_encode($myrow['Product_Pic']) . '" width="196" height="120">';?><p><span style = "font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em;"><?php echo $myrow["Product_Name"];?></span></br />RM <?php echo $myrow["Product_Price"];?></br /><?php echo $myrow["Product_Size"];?>MB <br/> <a href="cart.php?cartid=<?php echo $myrow["Cart_ID"];?>"onclick="return confirmation();">Remove From Cart</a></p> </li>
      <?php
      
    }     
     
   }
```

how to store add to cart item in php?
And then display it .
I've research many tutorial but I still cannot understand .
Please guide me.

Situation :
I click add to cart button and I manage to pass the specific product ID but i couldn't store it using session .

Comment: If you cannot understand the tutorials on the internet I doubt you will understand what people may write here. There's plenty of tutorials that you can pretty much just copy & paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using array_push();

```
    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $id);
```

And to display it:

```
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
        echo $value,'<br>';
    }
```

Should output something like:
2313
4324
4535
2313

Stating that those numbers would be the ID. If you want it to be names instead, just push the names into the session. However ID would be better as you can query the database and get the correct name each time, in case they've been updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll go and try. Will get back to u if working.

Comment: It's working ! Can add to cart and display already. But whenever I go to index page and try to go back to cart page the item remove already . Anything I miss out ?

Comment: You have to post your code. I would also appriciate it if you set my answer to be the correct one :)

Comment: i've uploaded. its abit messy.

Comment: it can only add one product to cart. After i add another product to cart. it replace with the previous one.

Comment: Turn this $_SESSION['cart']=array(); into if (isset($_SESSION['cart']) === FALSE) { $_SESSION['cart']=array(); }

Comment: Thanks ! Its Working Fine. Appreciate ur Help!